# Use a form with option elements to generate custom iframes

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

1

I am making a website for a school project.

The idea is a website that allows you to filter different results from Cricket stores in New Zealand and then have them all in one place using iframes eg. if one filter was to sort by lowest price, the iframes would have the URL "www.cricketwebiste.com/sortby=lowest/"

I've made a form so far:

```
<br>
<select id="brand">
  <option value="brand">Brand</option>
  <option value="graynicolls">Gray-Nicolls</option>
  <option value="kookaburra">Kookaburra</option>
  <option value="m&h">Millichamp and Hall</option>
  <option value="newbalance">New Balance</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Submit">
```

My question is: how would I use the data from a submitted form to generate these iframes so that it would go to a page with multiple iframes with different websites. that all have that filter on? eg. cricketwebsite.com/kookaburra

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in multiple ways. In all of them you'll have to listen to the events on or in the form element.

This first example listens for the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event on the `<select>` element. The change event happens when the value of a form element has been changed and triggers event handlers listening to that event. The event handler in this case is a function called `selectBrand`.

The `selectBrand` function gets the current value of the `<select>` element, which is the value of the `value` attribute on the selected `<option>` element. It then concatenates the value with the URL that needs to go before it and sets the `src` property of the [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element which changes the URL of the iframe.

Now your iframe content has been changed.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('brand');
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
const url = 'www.cricketwebiste.com/';

function selectBrand(event) {
  const { value } = event.target;
  const src = url + value;
  console.log(src); // This show the result.
  iframe.src = src;
}

select.addEventListener('change', selectBrand);
```

```html
<select id="brand">
  <option value="brand">Brand</option>
  <option value="graynicolls">Gray-Nicolls</option>
  <option value="kookaburra">Kookaburra</option>
  <option value="m&h">Millichamp and Hall</option>
  <option value="newbalance">New Balance</option>
</select>

<iframe id="iframe" src="brand"></iframe>
```

Otherwise you could listen for the [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event on a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element that is wrapping your inputs and other elements you need. A submit event happens whenever the **submit** button has been clicked in a form. This button needs to be an `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit"></button>` element for it to count.

The regular behavior of the `<form>` element is to send all your data in the form through a HTTP request to a designated endpoint. But we'll cancel that behavior with [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) which, like the name suggests, prevents the default behavior of a submit.

Instead you'll want to extract the values from the form that you need. You can do that with a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) constructor. This will create an iterable object with *name-value* pairs of the elements in the form. With the [`FormData.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) you can get the specific value of a form element, in this case the `'brands'` field, which is your `<select>` element.

It then does the same thing as the example above.

```js
const form = document.forms['brand-form'];
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
const url = 'www.cricketwebiste.com/';

function selectBrand(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { target } = event;
  const formData = new FormData(target);
  const value = formData.get('brand');
  const src = url + value;
  console.log(src); // This show the result.
  iframe.src = src;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', selectBrand);
```

```html
<form name="brand-form">
  <select id="brand" name="brand">
    <option value="brand">Brand</option>
    <option value="graynicolls">Gray-Nicolls</option>
    <option value="kookaburra">Kookaburra</option>
    <option value="m&h">Millichamp and Hall</option>
    <option value="newbalance">New Balance</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<iframe id="iframe" src="brand"></iframe>
```

I hope this is clear enough and will help you get further with your project. If you have any questions or comments, feel free to leave them below.

Comment: Hello, @Emiel Zuurbier. First of all, thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. Secondly, I've run into a problem. I think I've done everything as you've shown but my iframe will only display "it may have been moved or deleted" Everything is within the same file and I haven't changed any names. I can't paste all of my code because of the character limitation but here is the main result of a debug:
axError: Unexpected token '<'
Perhaps there is a better place without character limitations to continue our discussion

Comment: It's my pleasure. You could make a CodePen, JSFiddle or other online coding tool to show your code running. Sounds like a character is in a file where it should not be. Share your link of one the above options, with the error in there, and I'll take a look.

Comment: https://codepen.io/lukefisher7000/pen/dyGwdxr                                                                       I put all of the code in the HTML section; it seems it be fine with that though. Also, CodePen is unable to handle my XFrame bypass, but it works in Visual Studio code so that isn't the problem. Once again, thanks for this.

Comment: `Unexpected token '<' ` means that the `<` symbol is present in JavaScript in a place where it should not be. I suspect that you've copied HTML (because all tags start with a `<`) into your JavaScript which causes the error. HTML works from top to bottom. Keep your scripts at the bottom of the HTML, especially when they select elements from the DOM. Otherwise JS will try to select elements that are not (yet) there and things start to break.

Comment: One solution brings another problem! I moved my script down to the bottom and now when I select an option it says that the website refused to connect. This is obviously a problem with the XFrame Bypass module I am using but I tried using it on its own and it still worked. `<head>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>

        <iframe is="x-frame-bypass" src="https://playerssports.co.nz/cricket/" style="width: 500;" height="500"></iframe>
    </head>`                                                   That code works. Have updated the CodePen. Cheers.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
` Got this error again even when all of the script is at the bottom and I flushed it out for these <>

Comment: Okay, I see what you did. The component that you use, `x-frame-bypass` fetches the entire site and pastes it into the iframe, same way as you would download the entire webpage by visiting it with your browser. You're doing this because the default way gives you an error. This error is there to show you that this site does not allow you to use an iframe to display their site. So you might want to rethink your approach to your whole project, as iframes are notoriously prone to these errors. The other errors are compile errors which I cannot replicate.

Comment: So there's no way for the xframe bypass to work? How else could I do it? I'm thinking I'd have to fetch prices from the sites somehow, which sounds really quite difficult? I have 9 weeks to do it so I'm gonna have to find a reasonably easy solution. By the way I understand if you don't have the time to walk me step by step through my project, but your help will be thoroughly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Usually you would communicate with an endpoint on a server that would provide data, an API for example. I don't know the scope or assignment you are making but I would suggest looking for a platform which allows you to use their data in such a fashion.

Comment: Sounds a bit above me. Thanks for your help regardless of my failure and inability.